# How to modify down-sampled bitmap with Fresco Android?

Tags: android, fresco, downsampling

I want to display image from internet with blur effect.

I configured Fresco:

```java
ImagePipelineConfig config = ImagePipelineConfig.newBuilder(this)
.setDownsampleEnabled(true)
.build();
Fresco.initialize(this, config);
```

Load and display image:

```java
Postprocessor postProcessor = new BasePostprocessor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.process(bitmap);
            blurImage(bitmap);
        }
    };
ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(imageUri)
                    .setPostprocessor(postProcessor)
                    .build();

PipelineDraweeController controller 
= (PipelineDraweeController)Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                            .setImageRequest(request)
                            .setOldController(simpleDrawee.getController())
                            .build();
simpleDrawee.setController(controller);
```

The problem is the `bitmap` I got is full resolution bitmap instead of down-sampled bitmap, this make `blurImage()` runs too slow.

Please help me to modify the down-sampled bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify ResizeOptions as explained in the [documentation](http://frescolib.org/docs/resizing-rotating.html#_).